# Как подсчитать количество строк в категории R studio?

Tags: r, rstudio

Canada <- oly12 %>%
filter(Country == "Canada") %>%
group_by(Name)
Canada

При запуске кода выходит таблица сортирующая людей по имени, что нужно добавить чтобы просто подсчитало кол-во людей?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/41906878/4827341

Answer (score 1):

Не совсем понятно в каком формате данные и что именно Вы хотите сделать, но предположу:

tmp <-data.frame(table(oly12$Country)) # сработает если у Вас каждому человеку соответствует одна строка.

Если не подходит- покажите данные, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 1):

Есть в dplyr функция `n()` которая используется внутри `summarise()`:

```
Canada <- oly12 %>% 
    filter(Country == "Canada") %>% 
    group_by(Name) %>%
    summarise(
              n_names = n()
             )

Canada
```